# Maya Add Event not working (Right-click from dock)

Tags: calendar

I can add event on Maya using two options:

- the plus icon from the interface
- (if Maya is closed) right clicking the icon from dock then selecting 'Add Event'

But if the user interface is open, right-click and selecting 'Add Event' doesn't show the create event option. Doing this same procedure while Maya is minimized will only pop back Maya to screen.

Is this the right behavior or should I file this as a bug?